# Renaming Text Files That End In Numerical Values

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have fifteen files that are named ...cyclones_hrrr_(**1-16**) and I need to rename them to cyclones_hrrr_(**0-15**). I've written the following code using the mv command and it works but, I need something that's more efficient, perhaps a loop of some sort:

```
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_1 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_0
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_2 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_1
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_3 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_2
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_4 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_3
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_5 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_4
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_6 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_5
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_7 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_6
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_8 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_7
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_9 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_8
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_10 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_9
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_11 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_10
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_12 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_11
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_13 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_12
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_14 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_13
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_15 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_14
mv ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_16 ${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_15
```

Comment: Try [this](http://bencane.com/2013/10/21/5-bash-for-loop-examples-to-make-command-line-tasks-more-efficient/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in {1..16}; do mv "cyclones_hrrr_$i" "cyclones_hrrr_$((i-1))" ; done
```

#### Explanation

- `for i in {1..16}; do`

  This starts a loop.  The loop is run for every value of the variable `i` from 1 to 16.
- `mv "cyclones_hrrr_$i" "cyclones_hrrr_$((i-1))"`

  This moves the files.  If the files are not in the current directory, add the path.

  The shell allows simple arithmetic.  The expression `$((i-1))` returns `i-1`.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
p="${HOMEDIR}/hrrr/tmp/cyclones_hrrr_"
for ((i=1; i<=16; i++)); do mv "$p$i" "$p$((i-1))" ; done
```